# "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" occurred while using pandas df.ne

Tags: pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have two dataframes as shown below: `df1` and `df2`

```
df1 =
            emp_name    emp_city    counts  
    emp_id              
    1       one         city1       3   
    2       two         city2       1   
    3       three       city3       1   

df2 =
            emp_name    emp_city    counts  
    emp_id              
    2       two         city2       1   
    2       twoxx       city2       1   
    4       four        city4       1
```

Note: 'emp_id' acts as index.

when I try to compare the two dataframes df1 and df2, using `df.ne` utility, as shown below,

```
df3 = df2.copy()
df3['mismatch_col'] = df2.ne(df1, axis=1).dot(df2.columns + ',').str[:-1])
```

I encounter below error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I understand the reason for this error. It is because I have duplicate index which is `emp_id = 2`. I want to keep the duplicates. How can I overcome this error without removing duplicates?
I also found that we can code `ignore_index=True` (while concatenating two dataframes) to keep the duplicate indices but how can I code it in `df.ne` utility?
The reason for adding this piece of code `dot(df2.columns + ',').str[:-1]` in `df.ne` is to provide the names of columns (separated by commas) which has mismatched values in df1 and df2.
Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is a way to do this. But how can it even work, because `df2.ne(df1, axis=1).dot(df2.columns + ',').str[:-1])` returns **4** rows, while `df3` only has **3** rows?

Comment: @user17242583, It works even if the row count is not same. It is failing because of duplicate index value.